# Docker doesn't run both cron and Rails at the sametime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, cron, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've setup the cron tasks using `whenever` gem, everything with the crontab is working fine. However, when the docker starts up, it doesn't start the `cron` service. I needed to go into the container and manucally run `cron` to get that service running. I followed other questions and their instructions, but they don't seem to be working for me.

The Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.3.3

# setup /app as our working directory
ENV RAILS_ROOT /app
RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT

# Set working directory, where the commands will be ran:
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT

# Replace shell with bash so we can source files
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

# Set debconf to run non-interactively
RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections


# Install base dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y -q --no-install-recommends \
        apt-transport-https \
        build-essential \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        git \
        libssl-dev \
        python \
        rsync \
        software-properties-common \
        wget \
        wget ca-certificates \
        cron \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Installing the Postgres - This specific version so it doesn't throw the version mismatch when we do `pg_dump`
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" |  tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/postgres.list
RUN wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install --assume-yes postgresql-9.6

# Install node and npm with nvm
RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.0/install.sh | bash

ENV NVM_DIR=/root/.nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION v7.2.1

ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/$NODE_VERSION
ENV PATH      $NODE_PATH/bin:./node_modules/.bin:$PATH

RUN source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm use default

# Install our ruby dependencies
ADD Gemfile Gemfile.lock $RAILS_ROOT/
RUN bundle install

# Install the cronjob logger
RUN touch /var/log/swscd-cron.log

# copy the rest of our code over
ADD . $RAILS_ROOT

ENV SECRET_KEY_BASE a6bdc5f788624f00b68ff82456d94bf81bb50c2e114b2be19af2e6a9b76f9307b11d05af4093395b0471c4141b3cd638356f888e90080f8ae60710f992beba8f

RUN bundle exec whenever --update-crontab
RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile

# Expose port 3000 to the Docker host, so we can access it from the outside.
EXPOSE 3000

# Set the default command to run our server on port 3000
CMD cron && rails s -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem using following config:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.3.3
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron
CMD cron && ruby -run -e httpd . -p 9090
```

Then: `docker build -t test .` to build image

Then: `docker run -it test` to start image and I see:

```
[2017-11-27 19:27:03] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2017-11-27 19:27:03] INFO  ruby 2.3.3 (2016-11-21) [x86_64-linux]
[2017-11-27 19:27:03] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=9 port=9090
```

It means that simple http server is running
Then I do: `docker exec -it <containerId> bash` to get into that container

Then I type: `ps aux` to see running processes inside container and there I see:

```
root         1  0.0  0.0   4332   752 pts/0    Ss+  19:27   0:00 /bin/sh -c cron && ruby -run -e httpd . -p 9090
root         8  0.0  0.0  25900  2172 ?        Ss   19:27   0:00 cron
root         9  0.5  0.0  72156 14608 pts/0    Sl+  19:27   0:00 ruby -run -e httpd . -p 9090
root        11  1.0  0.0  20240  3284 pts/1    Ss   19:27   0:00 bash
root        17  0.0  0.0  17496  2120 pts/1    R+   19:27   0:00 ps aux
```

I also entered command `apt-get update && apt-get install vim` after that I made `crontab -e` and entered there: `* * * * * echo "foo" >> /root/bar.txt`

After one minute i see:

```
root@5ae6284ae2e8:~# cat bar.txt
foo
```

So everything looks fine with cron in docker

Also in container `curl localhost:9090` is returning HTML so it works.